# Expression - There is still more in the expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am using SPEL expressions and I am getting this error when my application is starting up.

```
ftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpressionString("'/processed/headers['file_remoteFile']'");
```

Getting the following exception:

```
EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'file_remoteFile'
```

What I am doing wrong here? Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess... `ftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpressionString("/processed/headers['file_remoteFile']");` ...?

Comment: Getting this error. Problem parsing left operand

Answer (score 2):

Note you have used 4 `'` characters. The `" ... "` are used to pass a String to the Java's method. The `"' ... '"` is defining that the parameter passed should be recognised as String itself as well. Each additional `'` character inside the String must be escaped with two ones `''`. The following code should work (untested, however the is caught):

```
ftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpressionString("'/processed/headers[''file_remoteFile'']'");
```

From the Spring framework documentation [4.3.1. Literal Expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-ref-literal):

> The types of literal expressions supported are strings, numeric values (int, real, hex), boolean, and null. Strings are delimited by single quotation marks. To put a single quotation mark itself in a string, use two single quotation mark characters.

Comment: It is printing it as it is. Not fetching the value of key 'file_remoteFile'.

Answer (score 0):

You need `'/processed/' + headers[file_remoteFile]`.